# Regex expression to match certain url behavior in my website

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following url

```
https://myurl/blogs/<blog-category>/<blog-article>
```

I've trying to create a regEx so i can thrigger a script only when i'm in an article.

i tried this among other tests but it didn't work and i'm not really the best guy building RegExs.

```
window.location.pathname.match(/\/blogs\/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$\/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/
```

So in my understanding the first part of this regEx `(\/blogs\/)` is trying just to match a fixed string.

Then next parts just tries to match any kind of numeric,character and _.- combination (which is basically the potential strings that i can have there)

However this is not working at all.

My piece of script is looking like this

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/\/blogs\/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$\/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/){
    // A code implementation here
}
```

Note: One thing that i noticed when writing this is that if i remove everything and just try

```
window.location.pathname.match(/\/blogs\/)
```

It doesn't work either.

Can someone help me solve this? I will also appreciate any guide that can help me improve my RegEx skills.

Thanks!

Update: to have this working i had to separate my condition into two things to get it to work properly.

It ended up looking like this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
const regEx = /\/blogs\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*/i;
if(path.match(regEx)){
   // My code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var patt = /\/blogs\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*/i  window.location.pathname.match(patt)`

You can try using this

Comment: Both answers helped me to have it but this is the actual RegEx that i used to solve it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:
`\/blogs\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*`
the "^" symbol checks that it is the start of a string which is not the case for the url in question

I would suggest using https://regexr.com/ for testing your regex to remove any other possible issues from other code